# Make Reminder Flow work when Event.DueDate changes

Tags: visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow, conditional

I have a Time-Triggered Flow that reminds people one week before the Meeting Due Date. That is easily implementable.

[image]

But now I also want to cover the use case where somebody changed the Due Date. In such cases the reminder should be rescheduled as well.

1. When I make the **Flow also trigger on Update** I run into this:

> For a path that runs asynchronously, configure the flow to
> run only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements
> or **select the Is Changed** operator in a condition.

2. When I add `ActivityDate.IsChanged == TRUE` as condition I get:

> A flow with a scheduled path that has a time source based on a date or
> date/time field **can’t contain the Is Changed** operator in a condition.

3. When I change the condition to check for `ActivityDateTime.IsNull == FALSE` I again get:

> For a path that runs asynchronously, configure the flow to
> run only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements
> or **select the Is Changed** operator in a condition.

***ADDED LATER**
I considered what commenters said and added a custom Checkbox to the Event and a separate flow to enable it first. To make this work in update cases, I Reset the checkbox in the original flow. But magically, the "Immediate Path" is not executed. It resets the field only when I move it into the scheduled path. But that is of no use to me.*

[image]

I am lost. **Is there a workaround to get that working?**

Comment: What you built here is a scheduled path on a record-triggered flow. Remember that your time-triggered workflow action timing will update if the due date changes.

I don’t think you need a scheduled path. Can you explain why you wanted to include one here. If you don’t need it, please remove it.

You can build another record-triggered flow on update to check whether the due date changed, and call the action.

Comment: @AndyEUtkan I think I want exactely this and also describe it in my question. I want to do some actions 7 days before a meeting happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion I think is coming from the fact that the flow is being configured to re-trigger when the `Event.DueDate` is changed.

What actually happens with Flow Time Triggers is that the Time Based Workflow re-evaluates the `Event.DueDate` against the Flow criteria when the Event is changed. Automatically. Under the hood.

There are the steps that the Time Trigger follows

1. Create a record that meets the criteria of the Time Trigger
2. Time Based Workflow record is created with a ScheduledDate set by the flow (e.g. 1 day before ActivityDate)
3. When the Trigger Date is changed (in this case Event.ActivityDate) the time based workflow automatically re-evaluates the Event against the same Flow
4. Because the Flow is creating a Slack post 1 day before the `DueDate`, if the due date has changed, the TimeBased Workflow.ScheduledDate is updated accordingly.

I'm pretty confident that combining a Flow Time Trigger with and Async Trigger isn't possible.

The reason being

- The Time Trigger should be triggered when the record is created or changed
- The Time Trigger must reference a date/datetime field
- The Async trigger requires the inclusion of the IsChanged operator or must be triggered when the record is updated to meet the criteria
- The IsChanged Operator is not compatible with the datetime field in the criteria.

Trying to get around this may well be possible, but I would urge against it because it will just create mess (i makes my head hurt trying to devise a workaround). Save yourself a headache and just just have two flows, one for your Time Trigger and another for the Async flow. :)

Comment: Really cool. This means I need just a single Flow with no entry criteria, no checkbox field and other complexities.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure if the Slack action you're using is compatible with this approach, but I would probably build this out in a Schedule-Triggered Flow instead of a Record-Triggered flow --

- Create a Schedule-Triggered flow that runs daily pulling in Events where `ActivityDate` = a formula date resource `Today() + 7` and add your Slack action right after it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That might be a fallback if the other option doesn't work. I really want a flow to schedule itself when a new meeting is created and NOT a flow which bulk checks every morning. I have many indicators that this is also possible.